# Adding a line-terminator in pandas ends up adding another \r

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am able to load a csv file fine into a pandas dataframe with the panda defaults:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)

>>> df
   distance  recession_velocity
0   # not a row                 NaN
1         0.032               170.0
2         0.034               290.0
3         0.214              -130.0
```

However, as soon as I add the `lineterminator`, the program seems to go haywire:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, lineterminator='\n')
       distance recession_velocity\r
0   # not a row                   \r
1         0.032                170\r
2         0.034                290\r
3         0.214               -130\r
```

The file indeed does have a `\n` line separator:

```
>>> print(repr(open('/Users/david/example.csv').read()))
'distance,recession_velocity\n# not a row,\n0.032,170\n0.034,290\n0.214,-130\n0.263,
```

What is the issue here and is there a way to fix it without having to trim all the column values?

Comment: Can you share more of your CSV? I am able to parse your sample fine with and without the lineterminator specified. I am running pandas 0.22.0. How are you creating the "file" variable? You can pass a filename to pd.read_csv()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python's file objects will automatically translate `\r\n` to `\n` in text mode. `read_csv` uses its own file handling, it will indeed see `\r\n` instead, so if you pass `lineterminator="\n"` it will really just trim that one character.

If you don't pass the `lineterminator` parameter at all, it will guess the line-ending style. You can also pass in a file object instead of a path. This may slow things down a bit, but it will give you the same transformation behaviour that you see when you do a straight read.

Comment: Apparently Pandas doesn't support lineterminator="\r\n". It throws "ValueError: Only length-1 line terminators supported"

Comment: Yeah, just found this out as well :). I'll correct the answer.

Comment: @filmor how can you tell if the file has `\r\n` or just `\n` then if doing `repr(data)` only shows `\n`?

Comment: Educated guess ;). You did use a straight `open` which would show this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on @filmor's answer, to print the non-python-converted data to see what is actually there, use the binary mode. For example:

```
>>> open('example.csv','r+b').read()
b'distance,recession_velocity\r\n# not a row,\r\n0.032,170\r\n0.034,290\r\n0.214,-130\r\n0.263,-70\r\n0.275,-185\r\n0.275,-220\r\n0.4,200\r\n0.5,290\r\n0.5,270\r\n0.6,200\r\n0.8,300\r\n0.9,-30\r\n0.9,650\r\n0.9,150\r\n0.9,500\r\n1,920\r\n1.1,450\r\n1.1,500\r\n1.4,500\r\n1.7,960\r\n2,500\r\n2,850\r\n2,800\r\n2,1090\r\n# Total,527'
```

Here you can see that the line separator is `\r\n`, even though without using the `+b` mode it shows up as only `\n`. However, pandas doesn't yet support multi-line lineterminators so this introduces another issue.