# how to remove '\x01' from the result of pandas.read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Got '\x01' While reading csv file using pandas.read_csv().

Original value in csv:  width 18'' x 18'' log  "is measured A or B."   "C"   "DFG"   ""   ""

Output :  width 18\'\' x 18\'\' log\x01""is measured\x01A or B.""\x01""C""\x01""DFG""\x01""""\x01""""

pandas version : 0.25.0
python 3.6

```
import pandas as pd
path='data.csv'
dataframe = pd.read_csv(path,   sep="," )
```

I have upgraded pandas to latest version and gone through some answers, but its not working in my case.
[Adding a line-terminator in pandas ends up adding another \r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845348/adding-a-line-terminator-in-pandas-ends-up-adding-another-r)

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7989

Comment: The github issue you link to says the file uses `0x01` as a field separator. Your code uses `,` instead. Is `0x01` the correct separator? Did you try with `0x01` as the separator instead of `,`, eg: `pandas.read_csv('dummy.csv', sep='\x01')` ?

Comment: I used `pandas.read_csv('dummy.csv', sep='\x01')` already. But i got the same issue

Comment: What was the frame supposed to contain and what does it contain? 1 column? 6 columns? What should they contain and what *do* they contain? The double quotes are the default text qualifier in a CSV file so Pandas may think that everything after `"is measured` is a single text field.

Comment: If you check [read_csv's docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) you'll see you can control quoting with the `quotechar`, `quoting` and `doublequote` paramaters. Start with setting `quoting=3` to *disable* quoting and check the results.

Comment: setting quoting=3 didn't remove this  `\x01`

Comment: Here i have remove it by using `re.sub("x01", " ", my string)`, but this is not the right way