# after writing text in csv, opening it doesn't read the '\n' char

Tags: python, pandas, csv, newline, carriage-return

I create a csv file in wich I put some lyrics of songs, using this:

```
with io.open('songs.csv', 'a+',encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file , dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(input_row)
```

where input_row is a list with [artist , lyrics]

Now when I open my csv, I notice that everywhere there was `'\n'` and `'\r'`:

For example:

**RAW TEXT:**

```
I went walking in the garden
I was tripping on snakes
And I ain't asking for your loving
I'm just asking what your love is gonna take
```

**Text from the pandas dataframe after reading the csv:**

```
"\r\n\r\r\nI went walking in the garden\r\nI was tripping on snakes\r\nAnd I ain't asking for your loving\r\nI'm just asking what your love is gonna take\r\n\r\n
```

(btw I'm using Pycharm and in the overwiev of the dataset, those escape chars are not visible , so I have some words attached.)

I'm cleaning the column using

```
    data['lyrics'] = data['lyrics'].replace(r'\\[n]', ' ',regex = True)
    data['lyrics'] = data['lyrics'].replace(r'\\[r]', ' ', regex=True)
```

but when I print the text, nothing change.

Am I doing something wrong or is not a problem and I can simply ignore it??

Comment: @Błotosmętek not sure, now the poit was: why the line code that i wrote don't remove those \n and \r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Pandas has problems correctly guessing the type of line endings (Unix/Linux - `\n`, Windows - `\r\n`). Try the suggested here: [Adding a line-terminator in pandas ends up adding another \r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845348/adding-a-line-terminator-in-pandas-ends-up-adding-another-r) solution of passing a file object to `read_csv` instead of passing the filename:

```
with open('songs.csv', 'r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
    df = pandas.read_csv(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data['lyrics'] = data['lyrics'].str.strip()
```