# I keep getting \r appended at the end of each row when I parse csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to clean a certain column in my csv files, to which when I pass them into pandas, it leaves a trailing \r for every row.

`54147799,xxx_54147799,xxx_1442517,ALARM_NORMALIZED,xxx,xxx,2023-01-01 00:12:05.168,null,1,NORMAL,xxx/xxx/ATI,xxx,3,ATI System Mode,2,4,-1,-1\r`

Please help me improve on my script such that the \r doesn't appear.

My csv files are effectively unparseable into Elasticsearch because of the \r. The 18th column is expect to receive only numbers, not alpha-numeria.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import csv
import os
import re

def format_location(location):
    if location and isinstance(location, str) and re.match(r'^\d+$', location):  # Check if the cell contains only digits
        if len(location) == 3:
            return f"9{location}2"  # Prepend '9' and append '2' to 3-digit numbers
        elif len(location) == 5:
            return location  # Return the original 5-digit value
    return location  # Return the original value for non-numeric or incorrect length values
    
def drop_extra_column(input_directory, intermediate_directory):
    # Check all files in the input directory
    for file in input_directory.iterdir():
        if file.suffix == '.csv':
            try:
                # Read CSV file using Pandas with error handling to warn and skip problematic lines
                with open(file, 'r') as f: pd.read_csv(f)
                df = pd.read_csv(f)

                # Check if DataFrame has more than 18 columns
                if len(df.columns) > 18:
                    # Drop the 19th column (index 18)
                    df.drop(df.columns[18], axis=1, inplace=True)

                    # Define the output file path
                    intermediate_path = intermediate_directory / f"{file.name}"

                    # Write back to the CSV file in the output directory using Pandas
                    df.to_csv(intermediate_path, index=False)
                    print(f"Processed data saved to '{intermediate_path}'")

                else:
                    print(f"No extra column found in '{file.name}'. Skipping this file.")

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing file '{file.name}': {e}. Skipping this file.")
                continue

def process_csv_files(intermediate_directory, output_directory):
    # Check all files in the input directory
   for file in intermediate_directory.iterdir():
        if file.suffix == '.csv':
            try:
                # Read CSV file using Pandas
                with open(file, 'r') as f: pd.read_csv(f)
                df = pd.read_csv(f)
 
                # Apply formatting to 'location' column only for numeric cells
                if 'location' in df.columns:
                    df['location'] = df['location'].apply(format_location)

                # Define the output file path
                output_path = output_directory / f"{file.name}"

                # Write back to the CSV file in the output directory using Pandas
                df.to_csv(output_path, index=False)
                print(f"Formatted data saved to '{output_path}'")

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing file '{file.name}': {e}. Skipping this file.")
                continue

# Replace 'input/path/to/directory' and 'output/path/to/directory' with appropriate directory paths
input_csv_directory = Path("C:/Users/ethan/OneDrive/Documents/docker-env/logstash-standard/xxx/2023/01-Jan-23")
intermediate_csv_directory = Path("C:/Users/ethan/OneDrive/Documents/docker-env/logstash-standard/xxx/2023/Test")
output_csv_directory = Path("C:/Users/ethan/OneDrive/Documents/docker-env/logstash-standard/xxx/2023/Test")

# Process CSV files in the input directory and save processed files to the output directory
#drop_extra_column(input_csv_directory, intermediate_csv_directory)

# Process CSV files in the input directory and save processed files to the output directory
process_csv_files(input_csv_directory, output_csv_directory)

#process_csv_files(input_csv_directory, output_csv_directory)
```

**24/11/23 UPDATE**
Included in `with open('my.csv' , 'r') as f: pd.read_csv(f)`

`Error processing file 'events2023-01-24.csv': Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 18 fields in line 6370, saw 19 . Skipping this file.`

The 19th column on my csv rarely has data but apparently some rows out of the 100k+ rows still have it. I'm not sure what to make of this and can this problem be solved or not?

Comment: read up on LF and CRLF (and the differences between Linux and windows). This is correct AND expected behavior.

Comment: To clarify - are you saying that when Pandas reads the file in, it has a `\r` on the end, or that when Pandas writes the file out, it has a `\r` on the end?

Comment: @NickODell Pandas reads and writes using OS defaults, my guess is that the CSV was generated in Windows which uses CRLF, and is now being processed in a Linux (macOS, etc.) environment that uses LF.

Comment: When pandas writes the file out, there is an `\r` at the end

Comment: @OM222O That explains. Because I'm using docker container logstash to ingest my processed csv files. Yeah the docker is running on wsl. So every time \r goes in, it cannot be parsed. Damn, how am i supposed to clean my data henceforth?

Comment: @Ethan777 either use converters to strip the lines or try to mess with the `lineterminator` of the `read_csv`.

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845348/adding-a-line-terminator-in-pandas-ends-up-adding-another-r `If you don't pass the lineterminator parameter at all, it will guess the line-ending style. ` , but in the first place, my csv files never had a line terminator at the end of each row. What kind of converters do u suggest? Sorry still quite new to this.

Comment: @Ethan777 based on the stack question you posted: try to pass the actual file object: `with open('my.csv' , 'r') as f: pd.read_csv(f)` and see if it works. If not, your converter should be something like: `int(value.strip())`. I can see you're doing some manual conversion using `format_location`, but you can easily do this when the file is being parsed if you supply converters to the method. Read the docs on how to do that

Comment: Please refer to my latest update as of 24/11/23. I tried the changes but nothing checks out.

How exactly can I infuse int(value.strip()) ?

Comment: Please make a [mre]. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Sorry I dont really know how to do it properly. Or its what you're asking for. I dont have much time on me to fact-find. I need solution fast.


I have alr pasted my latest-cut of script up there and included an update on the latest error I'm getting. Which is about the mismatch of columns read into the csv file.

Do you want like a 5-6 row sample of data?

Comment: @Ethan777 I'm just seeing this now. You need to @-tag people you're replying to, otherwise they won't get a notification. Yes, I'm asking for a sample of your data, but also minimal code. See the links; [if you're in a rush, don't expect great answers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest); posting here is often slow and methodical, though conversely, often you can find an answer faster by doing your own research. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Give me 15mins. I managed to solve this issue already thru another perpsective. Waiting for the post time out to expire

Answer (score 0):

I have also solved this problem from the Elastic perspective instead of Python.

Used

```
filter {
mutate {
    gsub => ["message", "\r", ""]
}
```

}

in `logstash.conf` to arrest the `\r` and remove it before the json message is ingested into the pipeline for further dissection as an Elasticsearch Index entry.

For those on Elasticsearch, you may want to learn my solution if you are using python, pandas and their read/write functions to clean data - and get unnecessary carriage returns like \r or \n that dirty your data for logstash to ingest.